# Executing two gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs

Recently we created a separate codebase for our mobile site m.xyz.com and optimized it for performance. We implemented grunt in that codebase. Now, we are planning to use the same codebase for our upcoming new desktop version. so, we are structuring one codebase as mobile / desktop.

Now, the whole project have only one Gruntfile.js written for mobile. How can I split the task  for mobile / desktop ? Say, if I execute "grunt mobile" mobile gruntfile.js get executed. If I type "grunt desktop" desktop gruntfile.js get executed. Are there any other way to resolve this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to parse the command line arguments yourself, it would make the most sense to set an option. Call it like `grunt task --mobile`.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    if(grunt.option('mobile')) {
        require('Gruntfile.mobile.js')(grunt);
    } else if(grunt.option('desktop')) {
        require('Gruntfile.desktop.js')(grunt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created two file Gruntfile.mobile.js and Gruntfile.desktop.js

My Gruntfile.js look like this

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    if (grunt.option("option") == 'mobile') {
        require('./Gruntfile.mobile.js')(grunt);
    } else if (grunt.option("option") == 'desktop') {
        require('./Gruntfile.desktop.js')(grunt);
    }
};
```

My command line: `grunt --option=mobile` for mobile and `grunt --option=desktop` for desktop